# Squeak: getting the source code of a method in run-time

Tags: debugging, squeak

I'm writing a small program that modifies a method during run-time in squeak.
I saw that in squeak there is a method called `getSource` (defined in CompiledMethod class), that returns the source code of the compiled method.

How do I get the source code of a method if my input is a Symbol that is corresponding to a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know the class in which the method is defined, then you can access the `CompiledMethod` via, eg,

```
theClass >> methodSelectorSymbol
```

or

```
theClass compiledMethodAt: methodSelectorSymbol
```

with `theClass` being the class with the method and `methodSelectorSymbol` is the Symbol that corresponds to the method, ie, your input. 
There are further approaches, too.
For example,

```
theClass lookupSelector: methodSelectorSymbol
```

not only searches in `theClass` but also in its superclasses.

However, all approaches require that you give a class as starting point.